# order of levels in crossed design

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures, experiment-design

How can I determine if a factor `A` is nested in `B` or `B` is nested in `A` in a repeated measures design?
For example,

```
data <- data.frame(customer=rep(c("cus1","cus2","cus3","cus4","cus5","cus6"), each=3), brand=rep(c("A","B","C"),times=6), ratings=runif(18))
```

`Brand` is fixed and `customer` is the random effect. This is a crossed design I think because every customer rates the same brands. How would you determine which is the lower level, is it `customer` or `brand`?

In other words, should it be

```
Example 1    
       cus1     |     cus2
    A   B   C   |   A   B   C
```

or

```
Example 2
        A      |      B      |     C  
    cus1 cus2  |  cus1 cus2  | cus1 cus2
```

Comment: You say that it's a crossed design, and your data shows that too, since every customer rated every brand, so whence comes the confusion about a possible nested design? It is clearly a crossed design.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @user2974951. My confusion is to determine which is the lower level in a crossed design like the above? Is it `customer` (like `example 1`) or is it `brand` (like `example 2`)? For example in Robert's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified), there is an example of a crossed design where `class` is level 1 and `school` level 2

Comment: Talking about "lower" / "upper" levels is only relevant in a nested design, this does not matter in a crossed design, because there is no up or down. Read Robert's post again, the syntax he uses for a crossed design is `(1|school)+(1|class)`, as you can see these are not intertwined.